# Reading unicode txt in java

Tags: java, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to extract data from a .txt file that was encoded in Unicode because there are accents in it (French names). Below is a portion of my code. The output of string postalCode  has weird little squares in it (squareHsquare1square). My suspicion is the problem has something to do with the program treating the content as ASCII. Someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("postal_codes.txt"));
currentLine = in.nextLine();

//take first 6 char --> store as variable
postalCode = currentLine.substring(0, 5);
```

Comment: What do you mean "encoded in Unicode"? Unicode is not an encoding.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Sorry if that statement was incorrect; I'm not a genius. I think you can guess what I mean.

Comment: The point is that I can't. I can make several educated guesses, but there's no way to know for sure which one it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the javadoc for [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), it says (emphasis mine):

> The constructors of this class *assume that the default character encoding* and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. *To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream*.

In other words, you need to use:

```
new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
     new FileInputStream("postal_codes.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: And the winner is Mark! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like an encoding issue. I'm assuming that by "encoded in Unicode" you mean "encoded in UTF-8". Try this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("postal_codes.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

A `FileReader` automatically uses the default encoding for the platform. This often is not UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would solve the problem, but the output is the same.

Comment: @James - Try other encodings. If every other character is weird, then perhaps the file was saved as UTF-16 (or UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE). The best thing would be to confirm exactly what encoding was used to generate the file.

Comment: Thanks @TedHopp , that comment also helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use guava, method :

```
Files.readLines(File file Charset charset) : List<String>
```

of package

```
com.google.common.io.Files;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("postal_codes.txt", "UTF-8")));
String content = in.readLine();
postalCode = content.substring(0, 5);
```

Comment: [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) does not have a constructor that accepts a characterset.